# How to use only HTML and CSS for displaying a bar like given below

Tags: html

[Bar with 3 colors red,yellow,green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0K2TD.png)

Comment: I suggest you start by reading a basic introduction into `html`. Then, if you have a _specific_ question you need help, _then_ is the time to come back and ask it.

Comment: You can't because you will also need CSS.

Comment: When you say "only html" is inline css acceptable `<div style="background-color: red;"></div>`? If not, I don't think this is possible since what you're after is literally the entire point of css.

Comment: with css it is fine for me, but i doesn't how to create that bar with 3 colors, i tried with progress bar, but it didn't work out any other way to do this using css also its ok for me?

Comment: you got the answer already. I'll just suggest please go to w3schools.com and developer.mozilla.org after for more specific documentation. In that trip of learning, can drop by here anytime.
regards

Comment: How to set the width: value of the css by getting the value from the rest api? Can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a combinations of HTML & CSS.
Below code may help you:

```
<style type="text/css">
 .box { float:left;width:150px;box-shadow:3px 3px 2px #666767;height:30px; }
 .red { background-color:#ff0000; }
 .yellow { background-color:#ffff00; }
 .green { background-color:#00ff00; }
</style>

<div class="box red"></div>
<div class="box yellow"></div>
<div class="box green"></div>
```

You can see the fiddle here :[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrrv4tdf/)

Comment: How to set the width: value of the css by getting the value from the rest api? Can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

This is beginner level question, here us code with the combination of `HTML & CSS`

```css
.barCont{box-shadow:3px 3px 2px #333;width:240px;float:left;}
.barCont span{display:inline-block;float:left; min-height:15px}
.bar1{background:red; width:80px;}
.bar2{background:yellow; width:80px;}
.bar3{background:green;width:80px;}
```

```html
<div class="barCont">
  <span class="bar1"></span>
  <span class="bar2"></span>
  <span class="bar3"></span>
</div>
```

Preview at https://jsfiddle.net/itsselvam/9Lvz44bx/